# Pooled calculations sometime timing out with no reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, pool

I am currently executing Pooled operations to perform parallelized tasks. These tasks are openCV based keypoints extractions using the ORB method to score similarities between a source image and 3 other differents ones.

I can execute my pooled function once. It works.

If i do not perform anything else after the call, i can then make the call again, and it works again.

Execution time is always the same, about a second, and so is the CPU load behavior. The 4 cores load up to 100% and they drop after a second.

Now, if i execute between these two identical calls something like a rotation on a image, even if this image is not used by my pooled function, it does not work anymore.

On call the CPU wont load up, and the pooled function will eventually time out after 100 seconds.

Here is the code of the pooled function :

```py
def compute_pooled(source, img1, img2, img3, n_features, scale_factor, n_levels, lowe_ratio):

    pool = Pool()

    image_same        = same
    image_similar     = similar
    image_different   = different
    #confidence = get_match_confidence(image, img2)

    args_same = [image_same,source, n_features, scale_factor, n_levels, lowe_ratio]
    args_similar = [image_similar,source, n_features, scale_factor, n_levels, lowe_ratio]
    args_different = [image_different,source, n_features, scale_factor, n_levels, lowe_ratio]

    result_same = pool.apply_async(match_with_orb, args_same)
    result_similar = pool.apply_async(match_with_orb, args_similar)
    result_different = pool.apply_async(match_with_orb, args_different)

    good_same = result_same.get(timeout=100)
    good_similar = result_similar.get(timeout=100)
    good_different = result_different.get(timeout=100)

    values = [good_same, good_similar, good_different]

    ## I tried closing, terminating, not doing anything..
    pool.close()
    return values
```

And here is the code of the called function inside each pool :

```py
def match_with_orb(img1, img2, n_features, scale_factor, n_levels, lowe_ratio):
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=n_features, scaleFactor=scale_factor, nlevels=n_levels)
    keypoints_orb1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    keypoints_orb2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

    matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors1,descriptors2, k=2)
    method='orb'

    good = []

    for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < lowe_ratio*n.distance:
            good.append([m])

    return len(good)
```

If i execute the following instructions everything works fine :

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

imgname_source = 'source.jpg'
img1 = 'img1.jpg'
img2 = 'img2.jpg'
img3 = 'img3.jpg'

dirPath = '/home/path/to/imgs/'

source     = cv2.imread(dirPath+imgname_source,0)
_img1       = cv2.imread(dirPath+img1,0)
_img2    = cv2.imread(dirPath+img2,0)
_img3  = cv2.imread(dirPath+img3,0)

compute_pooled(source, _img1, _img2, _img3, 5000, 1.15, 16, 0.67)
```

It executes itself in less than a second at 100% cpu load. If i call again the compute_pooled function, it works in the same manner.

Now, with the following function :

```py
def rotate(image, angle, center=None, scale=1.0):
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    if center is None:
        center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h))
    return rotated
```

If I call it between two compute_pooled calls, even on an other image than the one currently used, the second compute_pooled call wont work.

```py
## First call works
compute_pooled(source, _img1, _img2, _img3, 5000, 1.15, 16, 0.67) 
_img4 = rotate(_img1, 90)
## Second call times out
compute_pooled(source, _img1, _img2, _img3, 5000, 1.15, 16, 0.67)
```

What is the issue right here ? I absolutely fail to understand why the second call times out wihtout launching any calculation.

Here is the error. It times out failing to retrieve any results from the first .get() call.

```py
--> 223     good_same = result_same.get(timeout=100)
    224     good_similar = result_similar.get(timeout=100)
    225     good_different = result_different.get(timeout=100)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    651         self.wait(timeout)
    652         if not self.ready():
--> 653             raise TimeoutError
    654         if self._success:
    655             return self._value

TimeoutError:
```